# Ubuntu 21.10 - Syslog.1 is 23GB in size!

Tags: 21.10, syslog

Ubuntu 21.10 (upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 to 21.04 to 21.10)

I installed Ubuntu back in November to learn the OS and noticed today that a major chunk of my SSD is taken over by a single syslog file.

/var/log/syslog.1 is 23 GB

/var/log/journal is 4 GB

I tried looking for solutions online and in one thread a user asked to open the syslog's tail to see what's causing the overflow of data into the file causing it to be so huge in size.

Every 6 seconds this gets added to the end of the log:

**`IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!`**

I'd like to limit the size of the syslog file to a certain size (let's say 5 GB). If something more needs to be done (like preventing the same IPv6 line endlessly getting added to the file), please advise on how to do so.

I'm still a novice user so please be patient with me.

Thanks

Comment: Answer provided for reducing the size of logs. Your other question can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353666/syslog-is-filled-with-ipv6-mld-clamping-qrv-from-1-to-2, however only representing workarounds currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This site](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/clean-mint.html) explains how you can reduce the size of log files. Although written for Linux Mint, it is applicable for Ubuntu as well.

#### Reducing logs of systemd

1. Reduce the current size of the systemd log files to 50 M with the command

   `sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=50M`
2. Make the reduction permanent by editing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. Following command does that automatically.

   `sudo sed -i 's/#SystemMaxFiles=100/SystemMaxFiles=7/g' /etc/systemd/journald.conf`

#### Reduce the size of other logs

1. Delete the current logs:

   `sudo rm -v /var/log/*.log* /var/log/syslog*`
2. Then you make modifications to `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` to keep only one previous group of archived logs rather than several, and increase the frequency of the rotation from weekly to daily:

   `sudo sed -i 's/rotate 7/rotate 1/g' /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

   `sudo sed -i 's/rotate 4/rotate 1/g' /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

   `sudo sed -i 's/weekly/daily/g' /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`
3. Also `logrotate` is edited with a similar aim:

   `sudo sed -i 's/rotate 4/rotate 1/g' /etc/logrotate.conf`

   `sudo sed -i 's/weekly/daily/g' /etc/logrotate.conf`